# How to stop the materialize navbar tabs from underlining and changing color?

Tags: html, reactjs, navbar, materialize

I am trying to make my materialize navbar links not turn the color of the navbar/underline when I hover over them. See the photos for example. I am using react. Any quick fixes?

this is how it should look:

[image]

but it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Pretty hard to help you without seeing the code. That is not normal behaviour of navbar tabs so something is conflicting. One fix could be to reinforce the hover/active class. This is the actual materializecss styles taken from the docs:

```
.tabs .tab a:hover, .tabs .tab a.active {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #ee6e73;
}
```

It looks like the browser default anchor tag underline is being applied. So you could try:

```
.tabs .tab a:hover, .tabs .tab a.active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
    }
```

https://materializecss.com/navbar.html/#navbar-tabs

Comment: that just made them all underline and darken to blue. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this just to be sure..it should override whatever conflicting css

```
.tabs .tab a:hover, .tabs .tab a.active {
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: white !important;
    }
```

Comment: still nothing... and now my buttons underline as well. hmm.